# EF - context.Set<t> vs context.T

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Since month, I'am wondering what is the difference using **context.Set vs context.T** instead of syntax.

I illustrate this question with this quick code that tries to get UserName from User table information from EF context.

**context.Set Method**

```
context.Set<User>().Where(u => u.Id = userId).Select(u => u.UserName).Single();
```

**context.T Method**

```
 context.Users.Where(u => u.Id = userId).Select(u => u.UserName).Single();
```

Thanks :)

Comment: There is **no** difference. BTW context.T is a property not a method

Comment: So I should write my favorite syntax ?

Comment: It's preference / code style / whatever. There is no technical difference as the behavior does not change either way. `context.User` is nothing more than a slightly more convenient way to call `context.DbSet<User>()`. What you decide to use depends on your own preference or the preference of your team members.

Comment: The only difference is before using the property you have to declare that property in your context.

Comment: I Think there is a potential benefit on `DbSet<User>` over `context.Users`. In case you want to use generics to make a generic DAL Class it would be straightforward.

Comment: Yes, For the repository pattern for example. But in my current team they are using context.T that for me the syntaxt usefull because with dbset u navigate directly to the poco

Comment: For clarity, the `DbContext` method in question is called `Set<T>` and the return type is `DbSet<T>`. And `T` is not method, but inherited context custom property also returning `DbSet<T>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Sir Rufo already pointed out, there is no difference.
You can use

```
context.Users
```

because you declared a property `Users` in your context class that is of type `DbSet<User>`:

```
 public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

Comment: It might be worth to mention that context.Set<T1>() can exist without having a `DbSet<T1>` property in the context, if `T1` is configured in the model or referenced by another entity type.

Answer (score 3):

In some situations you need to use `context.Set<T>` because you don't know the value of `T` at the time of coding , it will be set in the runtime

for example in generic Repository :

```
    public abstract class Entity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class User:Entity
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }


    public class Product:Entity
    {

        public string ProductName { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    }

    public class Repo<T> where T:Entity
    {

      public IList<T> GetList()
        {
            using (var context = new ApplicationDBContext())
            {

                 return context.Set<T>().ToList();
            }
        }

    }
```

then you can use `GetList` with any entity as the following :

```
  var userRepo = new Repo<User>();
  var users = userRepo.GetList();

  var productRepo = new Repo<Product>();
  var products = productRepo.GetList();
```

Comment: Hello, I was looking at several generic repositories and nobody uses "using", is it really necessary?

Comment: the reason of "using " is to dispose the object "DbContext" and free resources  you can find more about this subject in this article http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/08/20/asp-net-mvc-tip-34-dispose-of-your-datacontext-or-don-t

Answer (score 1):

Performance tip: you can avoid the overhead of DbSet initialization by using an alternate approach such as the context.Set() API call.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-6-0-preview-5-compiled-models/#dbcontext-instantiation

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30836594)